# can't find the date style format in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2012

I want to convert this nvarchar column to Datetime format:

```
        "29/12/14 07:46:20 PM"
```

This style is good but has no time:

```
        SELECT CONVERT(datetime, nvarcharDateColumn, 3) AS [DD/MM/YY]
```

How can i convert it and keep all the date parts (date+time) ??

Comment: You are doing it in reverse.  `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 3)` is converting a `DATETIME` into a `VARCHAR(8)`.  You stated in your first line that you want to convert an `NVARCHAR` into a `DATETIME`.  Which is it?

Comment: Why format dates in SQL anyway? Do it in your UI layer.

Comment: @roryap the problem is i can't find appropriate date style for that. i know what you are saying. it's just an example.

Comment: @DavidG I imported a table from csv and now all the columns are in nvarchar format. i need to convert the dates to datetime format.

Comment: Can you just say it plainly: which way are you trying to go?  From `DATETIME` to `VARCHAR`, or from `VARCHAR` to `DATETIME`?

Comment: I want to convert from nvarchar to datetime @roryap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A datetime data type in SQL Server has no "format".  It is natively a 8-byte binary value.  To convert the nvarchar string to datetime, use CONVERT with the nvarchar column as the second parameter:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, nvarcharColumnWithDateAndTime, 3) AS NativeDateTime
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Note the datetime format displayed by this query is determined by the application your are using, not the SQL Server database.  Also, consider changing the table data type to datetime to avoid data integrity issues; nvarchar will allow storing invalid dates.

Comment: He wants the conversion to go from `DATETIME` to `VARCHAR`, not the other way around.

Comment: @noryap, the most recent comment says it is an nvarchar column imported from a  csv.

Comment: @roryap The first sentence in the question says the exact opposite.

Comment: @DanGuzman what about the time?  date style 3 gets back just date and no time.

Comment: @Ariox66, style 3 will return a dd/mm/yy date string when converting from datetime to nvarchar.  When converting from nvarchar to datetime as in your case, the style indicates the format of the date within the datetime string.  The full datetime value will be preserved in the resultant datetime data type.

Comment: @DanGuzman Dear Friend, thanks for your help. do you know the date style of this format : "25-Jan-2015 19:24:01"  ???

Comment: @Ariox66, this format can be parsed to datetime without a style specification since it is not ambiguous.  To go from datetime to string, the closest format is 113, which will require inserting the dashes manually.  `STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 113), 3, 1, '-'), 7 ,1 ,'-')`

Answer (score 0):

This one has time, however includes Miliseconds...it could be too much :)

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 131)
```

Comment: This outputs `18/04/1436  8:55:53:903AM`.

Comment: Oh crap. Was looking for correct formatting, but totally forgot about actual date (facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

This is a harder task that I would have thought.  This is the best I could come up with:

```
DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME
SET @MyDate = GETDATE()
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @MyDate, 3) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CONVERT(TIME, @MyDate), 100)
```